# Meta query not showing result properly

Tags: php, wp-query, meta-query

In wordpress posts I have custom meta fields (ship from, margin price). I want to filter post by these meta fields. Ship from fields contains multiple value (Example: A product can be ship from china and usa). Query is working fine while I am selecting china, but not working properly while selecting usa.

I am trying to figure out what is the issue with query.

The query is as follows:

```
$args = array(
   'post_type'  => 'post',
   'meta_query' => array(
        array(
             'key'    => 'ship-from',
             'value'  => 'usa',
             'compare'=> 'in'
        ),
        array(
             'key'       => 'profit-margin',
             'value'     => array(0,100),
             'meta_type' => 'numeric'
             'compare'   => 'BETWEEN'
        )
   )
);

$result = new WP_Query($args);
```

Here is the last query executed by WP_Query:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts  INNER JOIN 
wp_postmeta ON ( wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id )  INNER JOIN 
wp_postmeta AS mt1 ON ( wp_posts.ID = mt1.post_id ) WHERE 1=1  AND ( 
( wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'ship-from' AND wp_postmeta.meta_value IN 
('usa') ) AND ( mt1.meta_key = 'profit-margin' AND mt1.meta_value 
 BETWEEN '0' AND '50' ) ) AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post' AND 
((wp_posts.post_status = 'publish')) GROUP BY wp_posts.ID ORDER BY 
wp_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 12
```

Any input will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: When you say that the ship from field can have multiple values, how are these stored?

Comment: @JacobPeattie they are stored as string. like china,usa

Comment: You’re not really going to be able to efficiently query them if you store them like that. You should store them as separate rows.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `relation` argument for inner `meta_query` arrays [as described](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#custom-field-post-meta-parameters) in the Code Reference.

Also, when you use `'compare'=> 'IN'`, the `'ship-from'` value should be the array.

```
$args = array(
   'post_type'  => 'post',
   'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND', // note this!
        array(
             'key'    => 'ship-from',
             'value'  => 'usa',
             'compare'=> 'IN' 
        ),
        array(
             'key'       => 'profit-margin',
             'value'     => array(0,100),
             'meta_type' => 'numeric'
             'compare'   => 'BETWEEN'
        )
   )
);
```

Comment: I read somewhere that default relation is AND for meta query

Comment: Yes, you are right. Anyway, you have to check the `'ship-from'` value and/or comparison operator.

Comment: I have one question. I am passing array in meta value for `profit-margin` meta key, but in query array values automatically convert into string. Is there any way to change these values to numeric ?

Comment: It's becomes [_serialized_](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) string, and WordPress takes care about serializing/unserializing it. If you use WordPress' built-in functions to work with post meta like `update_post_meta()`, `get_post_meta()`, WP_Queries and related stuff you don't have to worry about value type and structure.